# How to remove unicode in rdd with spark-scala?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Data sample:

```
1991;113;High Heels;Comedy;Bos�, Miguel;Abril, Victoria;Almod�var, Pedro;68;No;NicholasCage.png
```

How do I remove the Unicode and map the strings to standard string format using Scala in Spark.

Note: I did referred to the PySpark solutions, but I am looking for solution based on Scala.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import `StringUtils` class from `org.apache.commons.lang3` and use [this](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#stripAccents(java.lang.String)) method

And then perform a map over your RDD:

```
rdd.map(word => StringUtils.stripAccents(word))
```

You can get the dependency [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.0) depending of what you are using (maven, sbt etc.)

**Quick example below with an RDD[String]**

```
val rawRDD = sc.parallelize(List("Tĥïŝ ĩš â fůňķŷ Šťŕĭńġ","Tĥïŝ ĩš ânóthêr fůňķŷ Šťŕĭńġ") )
val newRDD = rawRDD.map(word => StringUtils.stripAccents(word))
```

rawRDD

```
Tĥïŝ ĩš â fůňķŷ Šťŕĭńġ
Tĥïŝ ĩš ânóthêr fůňķŷ Šťŕĭńġ
```

newRDD

```
This is a funky String
This is another funky String
```